# Ngrx split action of items in multiple actions of item

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I'm trying to make a Ngrx effect that loads posts from multiple users. I already have a working effect that loads the posts of one user. How can I split the LoadUsersPosts effect into multiple LoadUserPosts effects?

This is what I'm trying right now.

```
 @Effect() loadUsersPosts$ = this.actions$
.ofType(LOAD_USERS_POSTS)
.mergeMap((action: LoadUsersPosts) => {
  const array = [];
  action.payload.forEach(user => {
    array.push(new LoadPosts(user));
  });
  return array;
});
```

I have put some console.log's inside the forEach but it doesn't seem that it is even being executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the basic task you want to perform is to transform and individually emit the values from an array in an observable stream. You can do the transform just like you are doing now though `map` would be simpler than the `forEach`. Then you just use `from` to create an observable from the resultant array that will emit each value sequentially. Here is a simplified running example:

```js
Rx.Observable.of([1,2,3,4,5])
  .mergeMap(x => {
    const transformed = x.map(y => y * 2);
    return Rx.Observable.from(transformed);
  })
  .subscribe(x => { console.log(x); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.10/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

this can be achieved with below code

```
@Effect()
  loadUsersPosts$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(LOAD_USERS_POSTS)
    .pipe(
      switchMap((action: LoadUsersPosts) => from(action.payload)),
      map(user => new LoadPosts(user))
    );
```

here switchMap operator will convert the outer observable into multiple inner observable based on the "action.payload" array using "from" Observable creator

"from" Observable creator will create observable stream, from the array by emitting one value at a time

map operator will convert that into action

switchMap operator is preferred than mergeMap. mergeMap will provide output for all the request, while switchMap will cancel all but latest request